unable to fix and install oyente

Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface Version:
0.4.24+commit.e67f0147.Linux.clang
Z3 version 4.8.12 - 64 bit
evm version 1.7.3-stable-4bb3c89d

$pip3 install oyente
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting oyente
Using cached oyente-0.2.7.tar.gz (35 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-z6tsk7au/oyente_bd8126403d9e40938446254928b9c9a2/setup.py", line 10, in <module>
          long_description=open('README.md').read(),
      FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.md'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.


If a package file is missing, that seems like something you would need to resolve with the package's maintainers - see also Update to Python 3 #411
